LSTM autoencoder for anomaly detection: Shifted results
I am trying to implement an LSTM autoencoder for anomaly detection in time series data. I followed a tutorial on YouTube Time Series Anomaly Detection with LSTM Autoencoders using Keras & TensorFlow 2 in Python and used the code provided in their Github repository.
However, when applying the code to my own time series data, I encountered an issue. It seems that the results are shifted by a step. The points marked in the image I attached should be considered anomalies, but the anomaly detection algorithm identifies the preceding points as the anomalies instead.
Results:

This is the model I used:
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.RepeatVector(n=X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(units=X_train.shape[2])))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=5, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)


Are you sure this isn't just an issue that occurs due to the way you plot the output? Do the indices output by the anomaly detection model start at 1 rather than 0 and hence you get a shift of 1 time bin when you plot the results?

@MattPitkin I've checked my data, I don't think there's a problem with it.

Devils Advocate? It is silly to run a complex LSTM on such data. You can find these dropouts with a 70 year old idea (Statistical Process Control), using no training data [a].
[a] https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.13807
Current Time Series Anomaly Detection Benchmarks are Flawed and are Creating the Illusion of Progress

Thank you @Eamonn Keogh, for your answer. While I understand that statistical models might be more suitable in some cases, I'm required to use a deep learning approach for this one. Since I'm still learning, would you suggest simplifying the LSTM model by reducing the number of units or any other adjustments to make it more manageable?
